# More efficient input in c++

Tags: c++, io

I have to read 9mln numbers from standard input, i actually wanted to do it like this:

```
base = new int[3000*3000];
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
cin.tie(0);
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        cin >> base[i*n+j];
    }
```

but just input reading is exceeding time(algorithmic task), any thoughts how to do this efficiently?

Comment: Looks like you could lose a loop and save some math with `for(int i=0;i<m*n;i++)  cin >> base[i];` Dunno if that will do much for you, though.

Comment: It would also be necessary for array index to be at at least a `long` (guaranteed able to represent more than 9 million) rather than an `int` (which is not guaranteed to represent that many values).   Beyond that, reading is always a relatively slow operation even if you fiddle with buffering and synchronisation, since it is then determined by whatever device is being read from - if you want to read a large number of values from standard input (which will usually be a distinct device rather than, say, redirected from a RAM drive) you need to accept it will take time.

Comment: _is exceeding time_ and that time is? You have enabled the optimizer?

Comment: Do you have to use a text format for your input or can you use binary?

Comment: What are you reading *from*?  Maybe that's the bottleneck.